# How to get the NextBillingDate for Recurring Payment with Trial Period in the Sandbox?

Tags: paypal, sandbox, recurring-billing

I am trying to set up recurring payments using the classic API.  In the sandbox I'm trying to understand, given the setup I have here, why I get a return result showing that the next payment due date is in 1 month, when as far as I can tell I'm configuring this for a 3 month trial period.   Here's the code I'm working with:

========================================================

```
Private Function CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType(token As String,
                                                           subscriptionName As String,
                                                           monthlyAmount As String,
                                                           startDate As DateTime) As CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType
    Dim reqType As New CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType()

    Dim reqDetails As New CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType()
    reqType.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = reqDetails

    reqDetails.Token = token

    Dim profDetails As New RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType()
    reqDetails.RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails = profDetails

    profDetails.BillingStartDate = startDate.ToString("s")

    Dim schedDetails As New ScheduleDetailsType()
    reqDetails.ScheduleDetails = schedDetails

    schedDetails.Description = subscriptionName

    schedDetails.AutoBillOutstandingAmount = AutoBillType.NOAUTOBILL

    Dim activationDetails As New ActivationDetailsType()
    schedDetails.ActivationDetails = activationDetails

    Dim payPeriod As New BillingPeriodDetailsType()
    schedDetails.PaymentPeriod = payPeriod

    schedDetails.AutoBillOutstandingAmount = AutoBillType.ADDTONEXTBILLING

    schedDetails.MaxFailedPayments = 3

    '== schedDetails.TrialPeriod -> trial period setup
    Dim TrialPeriodPayment As New BasicAmountType(CurrencyCodeType.USD, "0.00")
    Dim trialPeriod As New BillingPeriodDetailsType()
    trialPeriod.Amount = TrialPeriodPayment
    trialPeriod.BillingPeriod = BillingPeriodType.MONTH
    trialPeriod.BillingFrequency = 1
    trialPeriod.TotalBillingCycles = 3

    schedDetails.TrialPeriod = trialPeriod

    Dim basicPayment As New BasicAmountType(CurrencyCodeType.USD, monthlyAmount)
    payPeriod.Amount = basicPayment
    payPeriod.BillingPeriod = BillingPeriodType.MONTH
    payPeriod.BillingFrequency = 1

    Return reqType
End Function
```

On the return page I am doing this to gather the information from PayPal to show to the end user.   Since I am setting the Trial Period for 3 Months I expect the next billing date to show up as Today's Date + 3 Months.  Instead it is showing me Today's Date + 1 Month (Note: for the sake of brevity I am deleting irrelevant code from this routine):

```
Public Sub GetDetailsAndCreateRecurringPayment(token As String)

    '== CHECK ON PAYMENT INFO RETURNED BY USER FROM PAYPAL REDIRECT

    Dim detailsResponse As GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseType
    Dim details As GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetailsType
    Dim recurResponse As CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType
    Dim recurDetails As CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetailsType
    Dim profResponse As GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsResponseType
    Dim profDetails As GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsResponseDetailsType

    ...

    Dim NextBillingDate() As String

    ... 

    '== GET DATA FROM PAYPAL
    detailsResponse = payPalUtil.GetExpressCheckoutDetails(token)
    details = detailsResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails()
    recurResponse = payPalUtil.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile(token, MySession.ElthosPaymentType, MySession.ElthosPaymentAmount, DateTime.Now)
    recurDetails = recurResponse.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails
    profResponse = payPalUtil.GetRecurringPaymentsProfile(recurDetails.ProfileID)
    profDetails = profResponse.GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsResponseDetails

    '== CHECK FOR ERRORS - IF ANY THEN PRINT TO SCREEN AND EXIT SUB
    Dim errorsText As String = ""
    If (detailsResponse.Errors.Count > 0) Then
        For Each errorObj As ErrorType In detailsResponse.Errors
            errorsText = errorsText & errorObj.ShortMessage
        Next
        Lab_detailErrors.Text = errorsText & ". "
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ...

    NextBillingDate = profDetails.RecurringPaymentsSummary.NextBillingDate.ToString.Split("T")

    ... 

End Sub
```

Am I doing something wrong, or do I not understand how the Sandbox is supposed to work in regards to next billing date?   Any help with this is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Any advice about how to test this efficiently in the Sandbox would also be much appreciated as well.  Thanks again!

Comment: I notice that when I go to the paypal sandbox and look at the test account it does have the correct data there.  It shows:  

Amount to be paid each time: 7.99 USD
Billing Cycle: Monthly
Payments Start: Aug10, 2014 

That is correct.   But I can not find any documentation so far that shows me how I get the Payments Start Date from the response objects.  Any hint would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Communications with PayPal reveals that there is no object from which you can easily get the Next Payment Due Date after a trail period is finished, or the End Date of a Trail Period.  They apologize for the oversight, but have no plans to fix this either.  They recommend using the return information they provide in order to calculate what the end date of the trail period will be for the end user's review.